# Do something when last item with same class is hidden

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say I have few divs with same class `.box`. When I click on one of these items, I set `display: none` to that `box`. Is there a way to find when the last element with the same class (or in this case `.box`) is being clicked and `hidden`? For example, when I click and hide the last `box`, I want to alert something.

Here is https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/139/

I tried something like this but I don't know how to find and trigger this when the last one is clicked.

```
if ($('.box:visible').length == 0)
{
  alert('No visible boxes');
}
```

Comment: Sounds like every .box needs a `click` event that has this conditional on it. Shouldn't run unless they're all hidden.

Comment: Your code seems to work -- [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/140/). What trouble are you having?

Comment: try adding an action $('.box').on('click', function(){

or add a second class that toggles to make it easy to count instead of trying to check css. so .box.visible has the css tied to the class.

Comment: @showdev thank you. My mistake i was actually trying do something with `each()` and it didn't work.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood -- I see, you weren't sure where to add the `if` code. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put your if-statement inside your click action

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');

    if ($('.box:visible').length == 0)
    {
      alert('No visible boxes');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery you can use index() function to get the last element position, as follows:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this).index();
    // -1 because index starts in 0 
    var len = $('.box').length - 1;
    if (len == clicked)
    {
        alert('No visible boxes');

    }else{
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    }

});
```

Running fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/142/